# Disable SQS "Dead Letter Queue" Warning

Tags: php, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I've created a PHP worker environment with a cron.yaml file, which runs a PHP file every minute.

I'm happy with it. but, now i get this Warning status about a dead letter queue?

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. Application update completed 84 seconds ago and took 89 seconds. 5 messages in Dead Letter Queue (11 minutes ago).

I don't know much about SQS. I just want to use my working environment to run PHP files using cron. How do I disable this Warning status?

Comment: Nevermind, I've switched to Basic instead of Enhanced monitoring for the environment and it's fine now.

Comment: You should probably check that dead letter queue.  That should be events you failed to process.